# Count rows affected with multiple DELETEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I want to count number of rows affected in below script

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
USE db1
PRINT 'DELETING STUFF'

DELETE FROM oc WHERE a_col LIKE 'G' AND b_col LIKE '11' AND c_col LIKE 'P' AND d_col LIKE 'N'
DELETE FROM oc WHERE a_col LIKE 'Z' AND b_col LIKE '1' AND c_col LIKE 'R' AND d_col LIKE 'G'

PRINT 'SCRIPT RETURNED 0 ERRORS'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT 'ERROR OCCURED WHILE DELETING, CHECK BELOW ERROR MESSAGE'
PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

It always returns

> (1 row(s) affected)

for each delete statement and I was looking for a count of rows affected. Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@@ROWCOUNT`:

```
DECLARE @num1 int;
DECLARE @num2 int;

DELETE FROM oc
    WHERE a_col LIKE 'G' AND b_col LIKE '11' AND c_col LIKE 'P' AND d_col LIKE 'N';

SET @num1 = @@ROWCOUNT;

DELETE FROM oc WHERE a_col LIKE 'Z' AND b_col LIKE '1' AND c_col LIKE 'R' AND d_col LIKE 'G';

SET @num2 = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: And of course `SELECT @num1+@num2 AS TotalRowCount` to get the total count of all rows deleted.

Comment: What if i have 10 000 of delete statements and i need a count of all of them?

Comment: Then at the same time you write the 10000 delete statements you write the @@rowcount ones

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code can be simplified to a single delete statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM oc 
WHERE (a_col = 'G' AND b_col = '11' AND c_col = 'P' AND d_col = 'N')
OR (a_col = 'Z' AND b_col = '1' AND c_col = 'R' AND d_col = 'G')
```

Then you don't need an explicit transaction and you can get the number of affected rows directly from `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go through *`OUTPUT`* Clause which could return deleted rows which is something similar to *`@@ROWCOUNT`*

```
DELETE FROM oc 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE (a_col = 'G' AND b_col = '11' AND c_col = 'P' AND d_col = 'N') OR
      (a_col = 'Z' AND b_col = '1' AND c_col = 'R' AND d_col = 'G')
```